# Count the occurrences of a symbol and return a column with the count, but only in certain cases, in R

Tags: r

I have data that looks like this:

```
 structure(list(Age = c("25", "22", "54", "62", "86", "25", "44", 
 "54", "48", "50"), full_name = c("DOE, MARTIN", "SMITH, RYAN E", 
 "JOHN, KENNETH", "DOE, LAWRENCE A", "FU, EDGAR", "ALEXANDER, AL", 
 "BARR, DONALD", "STEVENS, RICHARD", "LUIGI, MARIO", "SMITH, GLEN"
 ), ems_interventions = c("Oxygen - Prehospital Cervical Collar - Prehospital Long Spine Board - 
 Prehospital IV Access - Prehospital", 
 NA, "*ND", "*ND", "IV Access - Prehospital Cervical Collar - Prehospital Long Spine Board - 
  Prehospital", 
 "*ND", "Cervical Collar - Prehospital Long Spine Board - Prehospital IV Access - Prehospital", 
 "*ND", "Endotrach Tube (ETT)", "*ND")), class = c("grouped_df", 
 "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), groups = structure(list(
full_name = c("ABREU, MARTIN", "ADAMS, RYAN E", "ADLER, KENNETH", 
"AGLI, LAWRENCE A", "ALBERT, EDGAR", "ALEXANDER, AL", "ALEXANDER, DONALD", 
"ALEXANDER, RICHARD", "ALEXIS, MARIO", "ALLEN, GLEN"), Age = c("25", 
"22", "54", "62", "86", "25", "44", "54", "48", "50"), .rows = list(
    1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L)), row.names = c(NA, 
 -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE))
```

and I'd like to add a new column that counts the number of chunks of words between the "-" in the ems_interventions column.  I.e. for "Luigi, Mario" who only had "endotrach tube (ETT)" done, he'd get a "1" in this new column.  For "Barr, Donald" who had "Cervical Collar - Prehospital Long Spine Board - Prehospital IV Access - Prehospital", he'd get a 4 in the new column.  etc..

The catch being that I'd like to filter the people who had NA or "*ND", and they'd get a zero.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's just `"-"` you're using to split the strings, we can first `strsplit` the relevant column, and then count the length of each element of that list.

```r
ungroup(dat) %>%
  mutate(
    counts = if_else(ems_interventions %in% c(NA, "*ND"), 0L,
                     lengths(strsplit(ems_interventions, "-")))
  ) %>%
  select(counts, everything())
# # A tibble: 10 x 4
#    counts Age   full_name      ems_interventions                                                
#     <int> <chr> <chr>          <chr>                                                            
#  1      5 25    DOE, MARTIN    "Oxygen - Prehospital Cervical Collar - Prehospital Long Spine B~
#  2      0 22    SMITH, RYAN E  <NA>                                                             
#  3      0 54    JOHN, KENNETH  *ND                                                              
#  4      0 62    DOE, LAWRENCE~ *ND                                                              
#  5      4 86    FU, EDGAR      "IV Access - Prehospital Cervical Collar - Prehospital Long Spin~
#  6      0 25    ALEXANDER, AL  *ND                                                              
#  7      4 44    BARR, DONALD   Cervical Collar - Prehospital Long Spine Board - Prehospital IV ~
#  8      0 54    STEVENS, RICH~ *ND                                                              
#  9      1 48    LUIGI, MARIO   Endotrach Tube (ETT)                                             
# 10      0 50    SMITH, GLEN    *ND
```

(I reordered the columns just to make it more readable, `counts` first.)

FYI: the reason I skipped base R was because the provided data sample is a `tibble`, suggesting the preference for `tidyverse`-based solutions. For a mere base-R solution, use `ifelse` instead of `if_else`, and prepend variable names with `dat$`. *shrug*)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest approach with `tidyr::unnest` (I take advantage of the fact that your data is already grouped):

```
library(tidyverse)    
# this just counts
data %>%
  mutate(
    ems_list = str_split(ems_interventions, " - "),
    ems_length = map_int(ems_list, length)
  )

# to filter some of elements - unnest them:
data %>%
  mutate(
    ems_list = str_split(ems_interventions, " - "),
    ems_length = map_int(ems_list, length)
  ) %>%
  unnest(cols = ems_list)

# then filter and count:
data %>%
  mutate(
    ems_list = str_split(ems_interventions, " - "),
    ems_length = map_int(ems_list, length)
  ) %>%
  unnest(cols = ems_list) %>%
  filter(!str_detect(ems_list, "ND")) %>%
  summarise(ems_without_nd = n())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`stringr::str_count`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stringr/versions/1.4.0/topics/str_count).

```
# "base-r" version
df["Count"] = lapply(df["ems_interventions"], function(p) ifelse(p %in% c(NA, "*ND"), 0L, stringr::str_count(p, "-") +1L))

# tidyverse version
df %>% mutate(count = ifelse(ems_interventions %in% c(NA, "*ND"), 0L, stringr::str_count(ems_interventions, "-") +1L))
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest, and R base, solution is this:

```
df$count <- ifelse(is.na(df$ems_interventions) | df$ems_interventions=="*ND", 0, 
                   lengths(strsplit(df$ems_interventions, "-")))
```